# How can I add more than 1 group in menuitem in Odoo 11

Tags: module, menu, menuitem, odoo, odoo-11

I have a custom module with one tree view and one form view. The menuitem is this:

```xml
<menuitem name="Padres/Tutores" id="progenitor_tutor" groups="grupo_maestros" sequence="10" action="progenitor_tutor_action"/>
```

As you can see, only the group "grupo_maestros" can see the menu. 
The question is: How can I add more than one group to groups in menuitem to allow the visualization of this menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more than one group to `groups` by comma separating them, for example:

```xml
<menuitem name="Padres/Tutores" id="progenitor_tutor"
    groups="grupo_maestros,module.your_group_name"
    sequence="10" action="progenitor_tutor_action"/>
```